# Exporting Google app engine as WAR/EAR

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, war, ear

I have deployed my google app engine from Eclipse and its running good. Will I be able to Export this source folder as EAR/WAR from Eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Eclipse Web Tools Platform with Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform). Additionally, I also recommend looking at [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) in App Engine to create an EAR and multiple WAR files.

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java) of a couple of Web Applications packaged as an EAR.